# TLC5916-Q1 LED Driver Serial interface

Tags: led, driver, texas-instruments

I am planning to use TLC5916-Q1 LED Driver for switching of 8 different color led's and in application,switching takes place at fast rate.

**Datasheet**: http://www.ti.com/product/TLC5916-Q1

For interfacing SDI, CLK pins are used. As per datasheet, interfacing is as shown:

[image: LED driver interface]

I have seen one application where these pins are assigned to SPI pin ( SDI--> MOSI and CLK-->SCLK)

My question is can I assign it ( OPTION 1 ) to **I/O pins** or ( OPTION 2 ) to  **I2C pins**.

What are considerations while assigning these pins to controller?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is can I assign it ( OPTION 1 ) to I/O pins

Yes. The TLC5916 is not an SPI bus device. It is very similar, and most (ab)use hardware SPI to use it, but it is a simple shift register interface. Using GPIO to bitbang is how it would be used.

> or ( OPTION 2 ) to I2C pins.

No, the TCL5916 does not use I2C. TI has similar devices with I2C as seen [here](http://www.ti.com/product/TLC5916/compare#p515=I2C). The TLC59108 is an I2C version with near equal specs.

Comment: Thanks Passerby for quick reply. But what about clock pin? Can we toggle I/O pin at such high freq.?

Comment: @Electroholic you can toggle it at whatever frequency your microcontroller or SOC operates/limits at. Obviously a 16 MHz mcu will not be able to clock it at 30 MHz.

Comment: So, To conclude in one line "SDI and CLK are I/O pins only and my earlier assumption that they are SPI pins is wrong"

Comment: @Electroholic yes